# iCloud not working after TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, icloud, testflight

I was using a build directing installed on my iPhone from Xcode where CKRecords are saved and fetched from CloudKit. Then I uploaded the same build to iTunes connect. I downloaded the beta from TestFlight that should of been exactly the same, but not of the items that should of been fetched from CloudKit are there.

Comment: The same problem occurs to me. How did you solve that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the ICloud dashboard, click on the gear and select " Deploy schema to Production..."